# Finding proper tutorials for 3D Javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am getting ready to make next advance in Javascript, which is going to be in 3D field using I assume Three.js. 
There are some tutorials for beginners, but I am looking for some good tutorial... also if possible if there is online teaching tool, which will let me try stuff online and play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try things online here:

```
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/
```

Good tutorial:

```
https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291
```